# DACPAC drops existing users and permissions from database when upgrading through SSMS

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users, ssdt, data-tier-application

I'm developing my database through a database project in visual studio, and whenever I need to upgrade the schema of my database I like to use SSMS to do this using a DACPAC.

But whenever I use my DACPAC to upgrade the schema of my database, then the current existing Security Users and permissions for these users are being dropped. And I need them to remain in the database.

Is there anyway to configure the DACPAC to not drop users and their permissions whenever I upgrade my database using "Upgrade Data-tier Application" in SSMS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I usually prefer to exclude security items in this way:

/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions

However in that case, you have to set a few script in the post-deploy scripts to handle those items.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to skip that step when using the "Upgrade Data-tier Application" wizard in SSMS.

Your options are:

- Include the required security objects (`CREATE USER` statements, etc.) in the dacpac

  - This may or may not work for your situation, depending on whether you have different required security objects in different target environments
- Use sqlpackage.exe to publish the dacpac rather than using the SSMS wizard, and pass the `ExcludeObjectTypes` parameter, listing out all of the security objects you want to skip.  See here for examples, and what objects are available to be passed in: [SqlPackage Publish parameters, properties, and SQLCMD variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16)

Here's an example of the second approach:

```
sqlpackage 
    /Action:Publish \
    /SourceFile:"C:\YourDatabaseName.dacpac" \
    /TargetConnectionString:"Your connection string" \
    /p:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions"
```